# When a new badge is launched, are old responses taken into account?

Tags: discussion, badges, comment-badges

I am a bit baffled as to how I got the Pundit badge on SO. Apparently, I'm one of 7 elite pundits.

The description says "Left 10 comments with score of 10 or more"

That doesn't sound too hard. Only 7 people?

Is it only counting since the launch of the badge? Or is it for the whole history of SO?

Can you get multiple Pundit badges?

Comment: a lot of my comments make it 5, 6, 7 upvotes, but to get to 10 your comment has to be particularly funny or relevant

Comment: Dude, when you make it in I'll totally buy you lunch.

Answer (score 4):

Upvoting comments also was a fairly new feature. I remember when it first came out (now I feel like an old-timer ;-)

Comment: Do you remember when you could close other peoples comments on your own questions/answers?

Comment: old-timer? you don't get to say THAT unless you remember the password from the SO private beta! ;-)

Comment: I can't even _remember_ the password for the SU beta, which I only typed in a couple days ago!

Comment: @a_m0d: It's ewok.adventure (or is that a secret ;-)

Comment: I don't remember the password for the Private Beta. Luckily Gmail remembered for me. It was `_______maze`

Answer (score 2):

From past evidence (data analysis), badges are awarded based on events that happened prior to the creation of the badge. Being a pundit must be harder than you think ;)

As for how many you can receive, it's way too early to infer.

Comment: Weird. I must have a knack for it then. A knack I _don't_ seem to have for some other badges other people seem to get with ease.

Comment: I just looked at the "Pundits." I have by far the lowest numeric reputation of any of them. It's like I'm a Pundit prodigy! My night is made! http://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit

Comment: Congrats :) It is rather difficult to come up with a comment worthy of 10+ votes that isn't better suited as a question. Although soon I fear    that the CC WIKI police will be joining ranks with you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149778/is-software-engineering-dead

Comment: I'm going to assume Jeff made up the pundit badge just to make my day.

Comment: @Ian. Wow, that CC Wiki police action is making me a bit nervous. Maybe I should vote to close that sucker. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Comments don't get up-voted like answers do.  It's rare for me to see a comment with 10+ up-votes.

edit: I think part of this comes from not seeing the up-vote arrow for a comment until you mouse-over it, while up/down-vote arrows for questions and answers are always visible.  Maybe it's just too well hidden.

Answer (score 2):

It is over the whole history of the site.

I too was surprised how rare 10 comments with 10 upvotes is.

We *might* do a silver badge for something under this -- maybe 20 comments with 5 upvotes.

Comment: Now that comments can be voted on and have badges associated with them, it might be a good idea to allow people to view their top comments as well: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/reversal-and-pundit-badges/#comment-27798

Comment: The secret is in the # of pony references.