# Epic badge too hard for silver?

Tags: discussion, badges, daily-reputation-badges

Well, it's been [asked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34431/epic-and-pundit-silver-badges-are-too-difficult-to-get), but it's been 8 months and it hasn't got any easier.

Epic is by far the hardest silver badge. Only 103 of them have been awarded so far. The majority of gold badges have a higher count; except Copy Editor (80), Reversal (49) and duh - Legendary (30).*

Should the requirements be lowered?
(Disclosure of interest: I have 38 "exceeded" days).

* *(Not counting the new badges Announcer, Booster and Publicist).*

Comment: What's next? *Pundit too hard for silver?* or *Generalist too hard for silver?* ?

Comment: @BalusC I am pretty close to getting both of those as well, but they aren't exactly easy either.

Comment: Is this an exact duplicate of "epic is hard, let's go shopping", then?

Comment: All silver badges are equal, but some are more equal than others.

Comment: @Gnome +1 for the G. Orwell reference.

Answer (score 10):

My official answer is 'meh'.

If Epic goes gold, then what would Legendary be?

The rank of the badges is purely arbitrary.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Legendary, the first diamond badge ;-).

Comment: @game, oohhh!!! Shiny!