# Can we have a badge for up-voted comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More badges for comments / Bronze and gold versions of "Pundit"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45580/more-badges-for-comments-bronze-and-gold-versions-of-pundit)

I don't know about you, but I do see comments which are so good, they get massively upvoted.

I was wondering, if we had a badge for answers with lots of up-votes, why don't we have such a badge for comments?

E.g., comment with 40 upvotes gets a silver badge called "rhetoric?" and a comment with 80 up-votes gets a gold badge...?

What do you think?

Comment: Pundit not doing it for you?

Comment: But Pundit is a little different. It counts the number of comments over a certain amount, but I'm thinking about a badge for a single comment that gets a lot of up-votes

Comment: Related question; ["epic and pundit silver badges are too difficult to get?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34431/148310)

Comment: To be pragmatic about it, you should check and see how many existing comments would actually qualify for your badges as specified.  Also, should there be a time limit under which to garner votes, as lots of old comments still get upvotes.

Comment: According to data.stackexchange.com, there are 349 comments with 80 upvotes and 1201 with 40 upvotes ([query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/107210/high-scoring-comments?NumUpvotes=80)).

Answer (score 4):

There is the [pundit badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit).

See also: [More badges for comments / Bronze and gold versions of "Pundit"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45580/148310) .
(A rejected request for more comment awards.)